# How to fix "Library not found for -lAdust" error in xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

When i archive my react native app to publish to apple test flight, It'll failed every time with this error.  `Library not found for -lAdust`

Xcode vesion: **12.5**

React native version: **0.63.0**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:
Go to xcode and select you target.

```
xcode > target > Build Settings
```

Search `Library Search Paths`
After that make Release paths same as screenshot.

**NOTE**: carefully check `"` (quotation mark) have in you value box.

[image]